# Jquery UI Dialog with AJAX content, can't set focus

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I load content to jquery UI Dialog threw ajax and can't set focus on H1 tag.
And no metter what, i can't set focus to any element of the dialog, it just stack on last element of the dialog.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.home_story_small_top', function( event ){

        event.preventDefault();

        var storyId = $(this).attr('storyId');

        function success( html )
        {       
            $("#storyContent").html(html);

            $('#storyContent').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                height: $(window).height() - 100,
                width: $(window).width() - 400,
                dialogClass: 'noTitleDialog',
                buttons: {
                    Close: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                },
                open: function() { 
                    $('h1').focus(); 
                }
            });

            $('#newStoryTag' + storyId).hide();
        } 

        $.ajax({  
            url: "/showstory/" + storyId + "/ajax",
            cache: false,  
            success: success 
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any code that even looks like an attempt to focus an element...

Comment: I removed it, because it's not very helpful. I tried $('h1').focus(); and $('#storyId').focus(); and other...
Need to say, that H1 is added dinamiclly through ajax.

Comment: add it back so we can see where you want it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your HTML looks like but try waiting for a few milliseconds before focusing.

```
open: function() {          
  setTimeout(function(){$('#storyContent input').focus();},100);        
}
```

Note: I have never tried it but I don't think `h1` elements can't be focused..  Only input elements.

Try a setTimeout to pause for `100` miliseconds and then set the focus.  You may not need to wait `100` milliseconds `1` might do it.  You can test it out.

Comment: Yes, i tried it on many different elements (h1, a, buttons...) but it looks like focus() in this case is no effect at all ;(

Comment: I have one more thing to try.. If this does not work I would need to see your code.  You could make a http://jsfiddle.net/ to share it easily.  Check the update on my answer.

Comment: @user2781361 Please mark this answer as accepted it it helped answer your question, or give feedback.  Thanks